# How can i use the Keystore generated from Android Studio in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I Generated a Keystore using Android Studio 
Build -> Generate Signed APK -> and provide key info.

the generated file 
 - myKey

myKey without `.keystore` extension!
But In a terminal, as usual, we got the file name `my-upload-key.keystore`

But now I want to use this key `myKey` in my react native config Gradle file as wrote [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#adding-signing-config-to-your-apps-gradle-config)

So is there a way to use this keyStore in this configuration?

Or should I generated the key using terminal and follow the [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)?

Comment: as far as i know there is no difference in the way you create your `keystore`. Android studio just give u a UI that you can interact and create it more easy. just put the config in android native files and create your signed apk

Comment: @Amas But what about `.keystore extension` ?